# Jslint excessive comments

Tags: javascript, jslint

One of our developers are adding excessive amounts of comments to their scripts - every other line is a comment.

Is it possible to setup jslint to disallow this?

Edit; I know comments are good. But I think these kind of comments are silly and makes the code hard to maintain since you also have to update the comments.

```
// Function for checking if person is middle age or senior
function checkIfMiddleOrSenior(age) {
    // middle age
    const middleAge = 45;
    // senior
    const seniorAge = 65;
    // If more than middle age but less than senior
    if (age >= middleAge && age <= seniorAge) {
        // Return it's middle age
        return 'middle';
    }
    // If more than senior
    if (age >= seniorAge) {
        // Return it's senior age
        return 'senior';
    }
    // Return young
    return 'young';
}
```

Comment: There's no reason to encourage your developers to *not* write comments... if it bothers you - you can figure out a way to hide them, for example: https://atom.io/packages/fold-comments

Comment: As long as you're stripping the comments out in the production code what's the problem? Comments can be very useful.

Comment: Anyway, JShint I don't think so, but [ESlint has no inline comments rule](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-inline-comments) that might help.

Comment: When you have meaningless comments (e.g. "Return young") - remove them! Also, you should start a discussion with your team about [how to write a good comment](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/code-comments-the-good-the-bad-and-the-ugly-be9cc65fbf83) you'll find [plenty](https://blog.codinghorror.com/code-tells-you-how-comments-tell-you-why/) of good resources if you'll google it.

Comment: @Andy why should he strip comments from production code?